# Cocos2d-JS for mobile apps

Tags: javascript, android, cocos2d-js

Can you create mobile apps with Cocos2d-JS for android? I am trying to create an app for mobile android devices but I want to know if i can use that to create the app.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to develop a game for android, cocos2d-js is the right place for doing that. However, if you plan to develop a normal application, you should rather have a look at PhoneGap or Apache Cordova.